# Writing a bash script that turns a debian minimal install in to a crunchbang install, but for some reason it's not working

Tags: linux, bash, variables, automation

I'm pretty new to bash, but I need this script to

- install sudo and add the user inputted name to the sudoers file
- add repositories to /etc/apt/sources.list
- run "apt-get update"
- install necessary packages to get the system up and running with a GUI
- write the necessary configuration files to appropriate user directory.
- run apt-get update

I'm 99% sure the bulk of my code is there and correct, but something small is throwing me off and I'm not sure what.

```
echo "this script installs openbox and tint2 on top of your debian minimal 
install..."
echo "MAKE SURE YOU'RE RUNNING THIS AS ROOT, OR IT WON'T WORK!"
read -p "Press enter to start :)"
echo "input your username"
read NAME
echo "installing an configuring sudo"
apt-get install sudo
adduser $NAME sudo
echo "configuring non-free repos"
echo "##Debian non-free repos added by cbr script" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb http://security.debian.org/wheezy/updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "deb-src http://security.debian.org/wheezy/updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
echo "updating apt"
apt-get update
echo "intalling CBR software..."
apt-get install vim xorg openbox build-essential leafpad chromium thunar gnome-dust-icon-theme
echo "writing your bash profile"
echo "if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then" >> /home/$NAME/.bash_profile
echo "  startx" >> /home/$NAME/.bash_profile
echo "fi" >> /home/$NAME/.bash_profile
echo "writing your tint2 config file..."
mkdir /home/$NAME/.config/tint2
echo "#---------------------------------------------" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# TINT2 CONFIG FILE" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "#---------------------------------------------" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# For more information about tint2, see:" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# http://code.google.com/p/tint2/wiki/Welcome" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "#" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# For more config file examples, see:" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/3232/my-tint2-config/" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Background definitions" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #0A0A0A 90" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #121212 90" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 2 - task active" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #d8d8d8 30" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #d8d8d8 30" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 3 - task" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #000000 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #000000 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 4" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #888888 20" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #ED2323 60" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 5 - taskbar" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #000000 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #000000 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 6 - active taskbar" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #d8d8d8 8" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #d8d8d8 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 7 - tooltip" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 3" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #222222 90" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #222222 90" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# ID 8" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "rounded = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_width = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "background_color = #888888 20" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "border_color = #888888 20" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Panel" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_monitor = all" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_position = bottom center horizontal" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_items = TSC" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_size = 98% 30" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_margin = 0 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_padding = 0 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_dock = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "wm_menu = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_layer = bottom" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "panel_background_id = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Panel Autohide" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "autohide = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "autohide_show_timeout = 0.3" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "autohide_hide_timeout = 1.5" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "autohide_height = 6" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "strut_policy = follow_size" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Taskbar" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_mode = multi_desktop" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_padding = 6 0 6" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_background_id = 5" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_active_background_id = 6" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_name = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_name_background_id = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_name_active_background_id = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_name_font = sans 9" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_name_font_color = #d8d8d8 100" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "taskbar_name_active_font_color = #d8d8d8 100" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Tasks" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "urgent_nb_of_blink = 20" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_icon = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_text = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_centered = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_maximum_size = 40 40" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_padding = 2 2" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_background_id = 3" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_active_background_id = 2" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_urgent_background_id = 4" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_iconified_background_id = 3" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Task Icons" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_icon_asb = 80 0 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_active_icon_asb = 100 0 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_urgent_icon_asb = 100 0 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_iconified_icon_asb = 80 0 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Fonts" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_font = sans 06_55 6" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_font_color = #d8d8d8 60" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_active_font_color = #d8d8d8 100" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_urgent_font_color = #FFFFFF 100" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "task_iconified_font_color = #d8d8d8 60" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "font_shadow = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Launcher" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_padding = 8 4 4" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_background_id = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_icon_size = 24" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Specify icon theme names with launcher_icon_theme. " >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# if you have an XSETTINGS manager running (like xfsettingsd), tint2 will follow your current theme." >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_icon_theme = gnome-colors-statler" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Each launcher_item_app must be a full path to a .desktop file" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/terminator.desktop" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/xfce4-file-manager.desktop" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/gedit.desktop" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "launcher_item_app = /usr/share/applications/iceweasel.desktop" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# System Tray" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "systray = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "systray_padding = 4 2 3" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "systray_sort = ascending" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "systray_background_id = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "systray_icon_size = 24" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "systray_icon_asb = 100 0 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Clock" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "time1_format = %H:%M:%S" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "time1_font = sans 8" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "time2_format = %A %d %B" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "time2_font = sans 6" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "clock_font_color = #d8d8d8 100" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "clock_padding = 4 4" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "clock_background_id = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "clock_lclick_command = gsimplecal" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "clock_rclick_command = gsimplecal" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Tooltips" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tooltip = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tooltip_padding = 2 2" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tooltip_show_timeout = 0.0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tooltip_hide_timeout = 0.0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tooltip_background_id = 7" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tooltip_font_color = #d8d8d8 100" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tooltip_font = sans normal 8.0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Mouse" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "mouse_middle = none" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "mouse_right = toggle" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "mouse_scroll_up = toggle" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "mouse_scroll_down = iconify" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# Battery" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "battery = 1" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "battery_low_status = 20" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "battery_low_cmd = notify-send "battery low"" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "battery_hide = 96" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "bat1_font = Sans 10" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "bat2_font = Sans 8" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "battery_font_color = #FFFFFF 100" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "battery_padding = 2 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "battery_background_id = 0" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "# End of config" >> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc
echo "tint2" >> /home/$NAME/.config/openbox/autostart.sh
echo "updating the whole system..."
apt-get upgrade
echo "Done! Restarting."
reboot
```

Any help on getting this thing to work or suggestions on how to improve efficiency are much appreciated, thanks a bunch in advance!

Comment: What is wrong with it? Is something not working?

Comment: yes, your headline says "Not working" but your last paragraph is "how to improve efficiency". If it's not working, please add details, error msgs etc. Check that all of your `>> file`s look like you would expect. Good luck.

Comment: Also recall that each time you run this for testing, your `echo cfgInfo >> file` thingys are add the same lines over and over at the end of the file. I don't see anything that deals with that, but it may be in your setup (that we're not seeing). Good luck!

Comment: Yeah it's not working at all, nothing is being written, nothing is being done. I have no idea what is wrong with it, edited original post for clarity. Also I noticed that I've added \n where it needs to go. Thanks!

Comment: Wait, so nothing is being written into your `>> /home/$NAME/.config/tint2/tint2rc` (etc) files? You need to take this apart and figure out what layer isnt' working. As your heading says "crunchbang install", thats' something I don't know anything about. Did you try running your `bash` script by itself from the cmd line? Then what happens. Add `set -vx` near the top, and you'll get a verbose debug/trace with script line displayed, followed by line with `+` at front showng what values are being used for variables. If you can't spot there, then comment everything out but the first section.

Comment: Does that work? Did you `chmod 755 yourBashScript.sh`? It needs to be "executable" by the shell., Keep reducing what you are testing until something works, then add another bit until you see where it is failing. You should really be getting error msgs someplace. Do you have `2>/dev/null` (or ` ... &>/dev/null`) someplace? That will hide error messages. Remove that.  We'll do better with sections of code with error messages in you Q, so add that, and remove what you can of your whole script.  Thats all I can think of right now. Going to bed. **This** is why it's called **hacking**!;-) Good luck

Answer (score 0):

let's take it step by step ...

put the `-y` when you install & upgrade

```
apt-get install -y sudo
```

and

```
apt-get -y upgrade
```

and

```
apt-get install vim xorg openbox build-essential leafpad chromium thunar gnome-dust-icon-theme
```

Now, run the script and post the output.
How far are you getting?

Also, this line doesn't do what you think it does :)

```
echo "if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then" >> /home/$NAME/.bash_profile
```

Change all you `mkdir ....` with `mkdir -p ....`